# #Parse error details and modify your source file appropriately

Tags: c#, asp.net

Server Error in `'/'` Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'holidaysmasters'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.

Source Error:

Line 1:

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="index, holidaysmasters" enableeventvalidation="false" %>
```

Line 2:

Line 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Source File: /test_holidaysmasters/index.aspx    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4253; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4252

Comment: is `test_holidaysmasters` is a directory ?

Comment: whats is `holidaysmasters`?